# Generating a variable which records the number of repetitions

Tags: stata, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal dataset in Stata in which IDs are repeated, I want to generate a new variable which repeats the number of IDs (like the column "visit" in the image). How can I write the code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE4Qw.png)

Comment: You got a fine answer. Please accept it: both you and @TheIceBear will benefit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use: `bysort ID : gen visit = _n`